# Easy way to simplify expression within anonymous function?

Tags: coq

Assume that I need to prove something like the following:

```
x: nat

(fun _ : nat => 0) = (fun y : nat => if beq_nat x y then 0 else 0)
```

Since `y` is not in the environment, it looks like I can't destruct on `beq_nat x y` to simplify the right-hand side. Is there a simple way to simplify expressions within an anonymous function?

Besides being able to massage two functions to look equal, is there a way to deduce that two functions are the same by showing that they produce the same value on all inputs?

EDIT: I realize that I might be asking for the impossible, since those functions are not the same, it's just that when applied to an argument they produce the same value. I'm not sure exactly how Coq interprets this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a case of what is referred to as `functional extensionality`, where you want to prove that two functions are extensionally equal (they behave the same from the caller's point of view).

You cannot prove it directly in Coq (since `=` is a definitioinal equality, it is not true), but if you wish to, you can require this module:

http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html

which will provide you with axioms for functional extensionality. You can call the tactic `extensionality y.` which will give you access to the `y`.

Comment: Yup, that seems to be precisely what's going on. Assuming that as an axiom is not a problem in my case though, since there are no other auxiliary axioms.